# Intimidate - Always to threaten and fill with fear?

Tags: meaning

I work in the IT field (software development). Whenever we get some task to do I hear my supervisors saying,

> I will intimidate him regarding this (to do some task).

When I searched I found that the meaning of **intimidate** contains some threatening voice or fear in it. But I am sure that my supervisors didn't say it in that sense.

So is what they said above a correct usage? And does the word **intimidate** has a 'soft' meaning like **inform** (which I couldn't find) which would be more suitable here?

Answer (score 10):

**Intimidate** means "Frighten or overawe (someone), esp. in order to make them do what one wants."

Although this does not require violence, **intimidation** is always agressive, and is never a "soft" or "polite" request.

What probably has happened here is that your boss actually used (or has himself misheard and is consequently misusing) the verb **intimate**:

> **Intimate** (v)
>
> 1. To announce; to declare; to publish; to communicate; to make known. (Obsolete)
>
>    - He did proclaim and intimate open war.
> 2. To suggest obscurely or indirectly; to refer to remotely; to give slight notice of; to hint;
>
>    - He intimated his intention of resigning his office.
>    - The names of simple ideas and substances, with the abstract ideas in the mind, intimate some real existence, from which was derived their original pattern.

Comment: Yes. And as your examples show, **I will intimate him regarding this* is also incorrect; *intimate* requires the matter communicated as its Direct Object and must express the Indirect Object with a prepositional phrase: *I will intimate this to him*.

Comment: I think it's more likely that his supervisor is just trying to sound more intelligent than he is ;)

Comment: @UpTheCreek: and if any of my supervisors join http://ell.stackexchange.com and come across this question, I am doomed. :)